# what is the difference between " and ` in JS?

Tags: javascript, string, syntax

this is quite an easy question but is not obvious to me.

What is the difference between this:

```
function fesElsDeures(subject){ 
console.log(`just started doing my ${subject} `);
}
```

and this:

```
function fesElsDeures(subject){ 
console.log("just started doing my ${subject} ");
}
```

It seems that in the second option, my console does not recognise the subject as a different value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Double quotes or single qoutes are just indicating string. But in first example there are not single quotes. It's a **back-tick** (`` ` `` `` ` ``) and it allows you to use embedded expression( in this case 'subject' parameter of your function).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't to be confuse with ' (Single quote) with **`  (back-tick)**.

- " is Double quotes,
- ' is single quotes
- **` is back-tick.**

when you use back-tick, it allows you write multi line texts.
[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: I learnt (correctly, I hope) already, that Double quotes " and  Single quotes ' meant practically the same in JavaScript. But back-tick has really an influence in the code, different from the first two. Thank you for clarifying it!